# Creating a pandas column conditional to another columns values based on a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, conditional-statements

Goodday,

I'm currently trying to tag a lot of job-ads based on the job-title using python 3.x and pandas. As every company uses different terminology for their jobs I want to cluster them in a sensible way.

Currently I have a dataframe containing 40.000+ job-ads and use following code to tag the jobs in a new pandas column:

```
dictionary = {
    'c.*dev': 'c developer',
    'web.*des': 'web designer',
    'onl.*mark': 'online marketer',
...
}
for key in dictionary:
    df.loc[(df['Job'].str.contains(key) == True), ['Clustered Jobs']] = dictionary[key]
```

As the dictionary and the database is growing constantly. I wanted to ask whether there is a more elegant and efficient way to do this.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solution should be a bit simplify:

```
for key in dictionary:
    df.loc[df['Job'].str.contains(key), 'Clustered Jobs'] = dictionary[key]
```

Or:

```
for k, v in dictionary.items():
    df.loc[df['Job'].str.contains(k), 'Clustered Jobs'] = v
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. This looks much better.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It was my fist question on stackoverflow and I'm really pleased with the answer and the quick response.

Comment: @Jan - Thank you too ;) And if get `15+` points, you can also upvote all helpful solutions ;)